# ngClass interpolation not working

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Consider the following icon-component. Why does the `color` variable remains as the word color instead of getting interpolated?

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'nui-icon',
  template: `
    <i class="material-icons" 
       [ngClass]="{color: true, 'bordered': border}"
       [ngStyle]="{'font-size':size + 'px'}">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </i>
  `,
  styles: [`
    i {
      display: inline-flex;
    }
    i.bordered {
      border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  `]
})

export class NuiIconComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() color: string;
  @Input() size: string = '24';
  @Input() border: boolean = false;

  constructor () {}

  ngOnInit () {
  }
}
```

Comment: Where do you use HostBinding?

Comment: @yurzui scratch that i had wrong title - if you refresh the page you should see the actual one

Comment: from your code the `color` looks more of a 'style' than a 'class'. Is it so? Otherwise you should mention that in the styles array. Besides, the 'color' `@Input` seems to be a string which makes me think it was originally intended as a style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ngClass** accepts three types of expressions

1. *String Expression*
2. *Array Expression*
3. *Object Expressio*n

What you are using is ***object expression***. In object expression, keys are CSS classes that get added when the expression given in the value evaluates to a truthy value, otherwise they are removed. So, key will always be considered a string, not an expression.

For your purpose, you can use string expression as below.

```
[ngClass]="color"
```

or

```
[class]="color"
```

Refer: [Angular ngClass API doc](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass string expression like:

```
[ngClass]="(border ? 'bordered ' : '') + color"
```

or use `class` binding for `color`

```
[ngClass]="{ bordered: border }" [class]="color"
```